# ag-grid custom header with html

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am trying to use ag-grid to display the data.
I want to have HTML tags inside the Header column, but that doesn't seems to be working. I have previous knowledge working with ui-grid but this ag-grid is new to me, so not sure where I am missing.
Here is what I have tried till now:

```
var columnDefs = [
                   {headerName: "Workload", field: "workload"},
                   {headerName: "units", "field": "units"}
                 ];
```

Grid Options:

```
$scope.gridOptionsObject = {
                            columnDefs: columnDefs,
                            rowData: $scope.rowData,
                            headerCellRenderer: (params) =>
                                {return headerCellRendererFunc(params)}
                        };
```

// Header cell renderer function:

```
        var headerCellRendererFunc = function(params) {
            var headerColDef = params.colDef;
            headerColDef.name =  headerColDef.headerName;
            headerColDef.isMetadata = false;
            return '<h1 column="headerColDef"></h1>';
        }
```

Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: This only works for older versions of AgGrid (v18 and possibly some newer versions, but definitely not working as of v22.1.1)**

---

So finally I found a solution. This can be easily done without any special treatment for the header. Simply define the template for the header and use.

```
var header_template = '<span class="text-danger" style="height:30px;">Some Value </span>';
```

and then define columnDefs:

```
columnDefs = [];
customColumn = {headerName: header_template, field: name};
columnDefs.push(customColumn);
```

Comment: this will not work, `headerName` cannot be a template string

Comment: this works well, i have live production instance running with this changes.

Comment: may be in a very old version of `ag-grid`, but I still doubt it.

Comment: @UI_Dev, so does that mean u will downvote this answer? QUestion was never asked for ag-grid 17+ version...

Comment: Just upgraded from AgGrid 18 to AgGrid 22.1.1 and this no longer works.

Comment: help me plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450872/search-function-of-agsetcolumnfilter-customization

Answer (score 8):

I'm a developer at ag-Grid, hopefully I'll be able to help you out with this.

This behaviour is very easily achieved using a header template, which allows for simple UI customisations of the default header component.

```
//Athlete column definition
  {
        minWidth: 150,
        field: 'athlete',
        headerComponentParams: {
            template:
                '<div class="ag-cell-label-container" role="presentation">' +
            '  <span ref="eMenu" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-cell-menu-button"></span>' +
            '  <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation">' +
            '    <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-order" ></span>' +
            '    <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon" ></span>' +
            '    <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-descending-icon" ></span>' +
            '    <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-none-icon" ></span>' +

            //The line below is the key for achieving the solution
            '    <a href="https://ag-grid.com" target="_blank"> <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" role="columnheader"></span></a>' +

            '    <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-filter-icon"></span>' +
            '  </div>' +
            '</div>'
        },
}
```

To use a header template we add it to the template property of the headerComponentParams column property, in the column definitions of our chosen column (we chose the athlete column for this example). We've focused on customising the eText element here (highlighted above), this is the text in the column header. To transform the value to a hyperlink we've simply wrapped it in an anchor tag.

Here is a demo created using Angular: https://plnkr.co/edit/DVCbltCbbamkNqMo

Here is a blog covering this topic ([link to blog](https://blog.ag-grid.com/adding-hyperlinks-to-the-grid/)) and here is the page in our docs which covers header templates ([link to the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/#header-templates))

Comment: this is ugly , cant we render a react component in template , is there any way to render a component in header ?

Comment: Thanks, @Louis. I am trying to write a click event onclick of ref="eMenu" and pass "params" (ie column details) in the method defined when called. I am stuck at this. Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: could u help me plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450872/search-function-of-agsetcolumnfilter-customization

Comment: this is really ugly and it doesnt work. for example, i want to add a button in a header, and still keep the sorting, cant find a way on how to do that.

Comment: Can you please check this question also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047215/add-custom-attribute-to-ag-grid-sortable-header-in-angular

Answer (score 7):

First of all you can **create a component**.
Then initialize that component to the attribute of **headerComponentFramework** of **columnDefs**.

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerComponentFramework: StylingHeaderComponent,
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        field: 'name',
        cellRendererFramework: StylingsNameComponent,
      },
    ];
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if you showed the component framework.

Answer (score 2):

In my project I did something like this:

```
headerCellTemplate = function () {
                    var eCell = document.createElement('span');
                    eCell.innerHTML = '<div></div>'
                    return eCell;
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please note from the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0):

> Header components (explained above) replace the need for header rendering. If using header rendering, you should refactor your code to use header components instead. Support for header rendering will be dropped in ag-Grid v9.

That's if you plan on upgrading to using the latest features of the grid.

---

Now to answer your question... what you are returning from your `headerCellRendererFunc` is going to be the same for each column, an empty `h1` tag. It should display the column name if you do this instead:

```
return '<h1 column="headerColDef">' + headerColDef.name + '</h1>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the headerName property of ColDef(columnDefs: ColGroupDef[];) as

```
headerName: 'You message' + '<some-html>Message to display</some-html>'
```