# Add custom attribute to Ag-grid sortable header in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ag-grid

In my angular project I need to add `data-test-id` attribute to the sort indicator part in the default template that `ag-grid` provided as follows:

```
<div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none" role="presentation">
  <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation">
    <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text"></span>
    <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="ag-sort-indicator-container" [attr.data-test-id]="dataTestId + '_sort'">
      <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span
        ref="eSortAsc"
        [attr.data-test-id]="dataTestId + '_sort_asc'"
        class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden"
        aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span
        ref="eSortDesc"
        [attr.data-test-id]="dataTestId + '_sort_desc'"
        class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden"
        aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span
        ref="eSortMixed"
        [attr.data-test-id]="dataTestId + '_sort_mixed'"
        class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-mixed-icon ag-hidden"
        aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span
        ref="eSortNone"
        [attr.data-test-id]="dataTestId + '_sort_none'"
        class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden"
        aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the the default template of `ag-grid` header, the only difference is that I added `[attr.data-test-id]`.

I want to create a custom header template **without manipulating** the existing behaviour like adding label, text again and etc.

Here is what I tried:

```
  {
      field: 'updated_at',
      headerName: this.translate.get('COLUMNS.last_activity'),
      headerComponentParams: {
        template: this.getSortableHeaderTemplate('last_activity'),
      },
      sortable: true,
      lockPinned: true,
    },
```

and `getSortableHeaderTemplate` is like this in my component file:

```
private getSortableHeaderTemplate(dataTestEntity: string): string {
    return `
      <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none" role="presentation">
        <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation">
          <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text"></span>
          <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span>
          </span>
          <!--AG-SORT-INDICATOR-->
          <span class="ag-sort-indicator-container" data-test-id="loan_application_list_${dataTestEntity}_sort">
            <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span ref="eSortAsc" data-test-id="loan_application_list_${dataTestEntity}_sort_asc"
              class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span ref="eSortDesc" data-test-id="loan_application_list_${dataTestEntity}_sort_desc"
              class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span ref="eSortMixed" data-test-id="loan_application_list_${dataTestEntity}_sort_mixed"
              class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-mixed-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span ref="eSortNone" data-test-id="loan_application_list_${dataTestEntity}_sort_none"
              class="ag-sort-indicator-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
`;
  }
```

This is working but don't want to put html code inside typescript file and would prefer to have a separate component. Any idea?

Comment: Just FYI, you can use put your markup in an HTML file and import it. Most loaders and bundlers support this without any configuration. `import sortableHeaderTemplate from "./sortable-header-template.html";` and then `createTemplate(replacements: Record<string, any>) { return Object.entries(replacements).reduce((template, [key, value]) => template.replace(key, String(value)), sortableHeaderTemplate); }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad seems that it's not working. Can you provide a sample please?